# SharePoint large site full crawl impact

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search

We have SharePoint 2013 on-premises environment with search service application has 15 million items.

Recently we migrated the site with 150 GB data.

I have to do full crawl for this site and search server has free disk space of 200 GB only .

Will this 200 GB disk space be sufficient for full crawl?
Will the full crawl for this large site cause high CPU usage on SQL content db?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the marked answer in the page [Search Size in SharePoint 2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/da4135f1-cf34-4aa0-9761-55c474e4e1a7/search-size-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointsearch)

> your crawl database can be expected to ocupy around 0.046 X (Size of
>   data). So in your case you should be looking at about 1-1.5GB.
>
> by Sara Fan, Microsoft contingent staff, Moderator

. . . we know that you need to multiply the added content (150 GB) by 0.046, which is just shy of 7 GB. So I'd say it's quite safe to make a full crawl of the newly added content.

But since there's a limit on each Index partition to 10 million items, I guess you already have a second index partition?! If not, it's time to add one by following the guide in [Manage the index component in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/manage-the-index-component).

Comment: thanks for response. My question is,  while running the full crawl, the disk space generally increases to some extent and post completion of full crawl, disk space would be normal with  0.046% increase. So keeping this in mind, i am worrying whether that 200 Gb free space would be sufficient while full crawl going on.

Comment: It would be sufficient enough, since the process isn't one single bulk job eating memory and disk space. There are several processes (a total of six) going on in parallel and serial at the same time. If you're worried, just filter the content that should be fully crawled and take a subset of the data while monitoring available disk space. But you're far away from danger here, so you are safe.